# Black screen with only a cursor and security options when I plug my external hdd in

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

I recently dropped my external hard disk and it wouldn't spin after that and would only make some beeping sounds.

So, I searched on YouTube on how to fix it and opened it up and did [this](https://youtu.be/XIUn03p8fkY).

But, after this too, it won't open and as soon as I plug it into my laptop, my desktop turns into a black screen with only cursor and security options ( Ctrl + Alt + Del ). And as soon as I remove my hard disk, it comes back.

What can I do to stop this, as I need to recover my data?

Comment: Are you talking about an external HDD in as USB case or an internal drive? In any way opening a hard disk outside of a clean room is an easy way to destroy it.

Comment: External HDD. Oh, I didn't know that. Are they that sensitive?

Comment: Placing dust in a HDD (e.g. by opening it) is like placing big rocks on a highway - it will end up in a crash.

Comment: So, there is absolutely nothing that I can do now?

Comment: Use the backup instead. If you don't have a backup get the drive to a professional recovery center. And next time make sure your important data has always a valid and recent backup available.

Comment: I don't have a backup. Guess my only option is to go to a recovery center. *sigh*

Comment: Just to make sure: have you checked if the HDD is really the problem and not the external enclosure? The enclosure can get defect, too e.g. having a short circuit.

Comment: When I had opened up the hdd, the spindle head was stuck and not moving, so I think that is an HDD problem?

Comment: But how does this relate to the fact that I am getting a black screen as soon as I connect my hdd.

Comment: May be the HDD engine is defect and is drawing so much power that the computer crashes?

Comment: My computer doesn't crash completely. It's just the desktop that starts acting weird.